# Python: Merge up to 3 columns of a Dataframe into 1 but either of the 3 could not exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns

I have a Dataframe formed like this:

```
+------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col1.1 | Col2.1 | Col3.1 | Col1.2 |
+------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    0 |    0 |    1 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
|    1 |    1 |    0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |      0 |
|    0 |    0 |    1 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      1 |
+------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Now I want to merge the columns into one, like all Col1.* into Col1 where there is a 1:

```
+------+------+------+--------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col2.1 | Col3.1 |
+------+------+------+--------+--------+
|    1 |    0 |    1 |      0 |      0 |
|    1 |    1 |    0 |      0 |      1 |
|    1 |    0 |    1 |      1 |      0 |
+------+------+------+--------+--------+

df['Col1'] = df[['Col1', 'Col1.1', 'Col1.2']].max(axis=1)
```

This works if all 3 columns exist. But obviously not if I want to merge Col2 with Col2.1 and Col2.2 because they are not existing.

Is there a way with pandas or in python to do this task with some function or do I need to go the long way with a lot of if cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use string manipulation and `groupby` with `axis=1` and `max`:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str[:4],  axis=1).max()
```

Output:

```
|    |   Col1 |   Col2 |   Col3 |
|---:|-------:|-------:|-------:|
|  0 |      1 |      0 |      1 |
|  1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
|  2 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
```

Comment: Loving how succinct this solution is.

Comment: Thanks alot! Exactly what I need. Couldn't test it until now.